# Problemas na gravação e resolução do cálculo

Tags: php, html

Não estou conseguindo gravar o valor digitado no `input` e depois resolver o cálculo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="GET-name">Nome:</label>
        <input type ="text" name="nome"/><br>
        <label for="GET-name">Altura:</label>
        <input type ="text" name="altura"/><br>
        <label for="GET-name">Peso  :</label>
        <input type ="text" name="peso"/><br>
        <label for="GET-name">Idade:</label>
        <input type ="text" name="idade"/><br>
        <input type = "submit" value="calcular">
    </form>
    <?php
    $nome =$_post['nome'];
    $altura= $_post['altura'];
    $peso=$_post['peso'];
    $idade=$_post['idade'];
    $alt2 = $altura*$altura;
    $adpo = $peso\$alt2;

    ECHO $nome."<br>".$altura."<br>".$peso."<br>".$idade."<br>".$adpo;


    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Salvar onde? Em banco de dados? Que cálculo?

Comment: exibir em uma pagina HTML os resultados.

Comment: cálculo de adposidade corporal.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, há alguns erros de sintaxe no seu código, no primeiro caso:

```
Para pegar os values dos campos input via POST, o código não se escreve "$_post" e sim "$_POST" (tudo maiúsculo) como por exemplo:
$nome =$_POST['nome'];
```

Depois no calculo, você usou "\" ao invés de "/" para dividir.

```
Código certo:
$adpo = $peso/$alt2; o código aqui
```

Então, você consegue pegar os values e calcular normalmente.

Segue o código ajustado, fiz na cabeça, mas creio que irá funcionar:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<label for="GET-name">Nome:</label>
<input type ="text" name="nome"/><br>
<label for="GET-name">Altura:</label>
<input type ="text" name="altura"/><br>
<label for="GET-name">Peso  :</label>
<input type ="text" name="peso"/><br>
<label for="GET-name">Idade:</label>
<input type ="text" name="idade"/><br>
<input type = "submit" value="calcular">
</form>
<?php

$nome =$_POST['nome'];

$altura= $_POST['altura'];

$peso=$_POST['peso'];

$idade=$_POST['idade'];

$alt2 = $altura*$altura;
$adpo = $peso/$alt2;

ECHO $nome."<br>".$altura."<br>".$peso."<br>".$idade."<br>".$adpo;

?>


</body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Penso que o problema está aqui `$adpo = $peso\$alt2;`.

Se está a fazer uma divisão deverá usar `/` e não `\` então ficaria `$adpo = $peso/$alt2;`

Comment: Agora o comando ECHO está exibindo os nomes Assim: $nome""$altura""$peso""$idade""$adpo;.  ao invés de informar os valores das variáveis.

Comment: Veja esta resposta do @brnTwp https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/294650/79646